# to store style file in values folder for Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

In my android application I want to store style file in values folder like values-sw 240, values-sw 320 such that my application can run in low resolution phones or in phones  which runs on Android 2.3.3. Please help me in this.Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: what do you want to do ??? Your question is not clear..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: in my application i have a values folder in which i have style file when my application runs on high resolution device it takes the values from this style file, when i try to run my application in low resolution devices or in devices runs on Android 2.3.3 it again takes the values from same style folder. I want to create a another value folder in which i can store my style file and low resolution devices or Android devices 2.3.3 can takes values from this particular folder when running my application. Please help me in this